# Laravel Nova - Two "One-To-Many Relationships"

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, one-to-many, laravel-nova

Community,

I want to have two selects from one table in Nova.
It should be possible to select one Location in Laravel Nova as *start_location* and select one Location as *end_location*.

I've got an **Activities** Model/Table with a **start_location** and an **end_location**.

Furthermore I've got a **Location** Model/Table.

```
Activities - Table
---------------------------------------------------
   id   |   start_location_id   |  end_location_id
---------------------------------------------------       
   1    |   1                   |  1
   2    |   1                   |  2


Location - Table
---------------------------------------------------
   id   |   city
---------------------------------------------------
   1    |   Berlin
   2    |   Paris
```

#### Problem

How can I setup a "multiple" one-to-many relationship here?

My challenge is that I'm not sure how to map a location to activities.start_location_id AND activities.end_location_id.

Especially, how to select the two Locations in Laravels Nova.

#### Possible solution?

Activities.php (Model)

```
public function start_location() {
    return $this->hasOne(Location::class);
}

public function end_location() {
    return $this->hasOne(Location::class);
}
```

Location.php (Model)

```
public function start_location() {
    return $this->hasMany(Activities::class, start_location_id);
}

public function end_location() {
    return $this->hasMany(Activities::class, end_location_id);
}
```

Location.php - Nova Resource

```
public function fields(Request $request)
{
    return [
        ID::make()->sortable(),
        Text::make('City'),
        BelongsToMany::make('Activities', 'location_start'), // ?
        BelongsToMany::make('Activities', 'location_end')    // ?
    ];
}
```

Activities.php - Nova Resource

```
public function fields(Request $request)
{
    return [
        ID::make()->sortable(),
        Text::make('Title'),
        Trix::make('Body'),
        HasOne::make('Location', 'location_start'), // ?
        HasOne::make('Location', 'location_end'),   // ?
    ];
}
```

Maybe there is a more easier approach?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: did you try your possible solution?

Comment: My opinion, think as general one to many relationship. In your possible solution instead of `hasOne` use `belongsTo`. Also in nova resource update `location_start` to `start_location`your relationship function name. Same for `location_end`

Comment: Since my first approach wasnt working as expected, I've found a different solution.

Within Nova its possible to choose the Select-Field with the option type.

Select::make('Start Location', 'start_location_id')
->option(\App\Location::getId())

Within the Activitiy Model you need to define:

public static function getId() {
    return self::all('id'); // this will first return id objects {'id' : 1}
}

The only thing I need to do is to map the options field to the locations title, now. Still figureing out how to do this..